# 404 not found when loading chartjs library in lightning web components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, chartjs

I am getting 404 not found error when loading the chartjs library. Below is the code I have for loading it onto my code. I have read on the web saying the v2.9.3 is not locker service compatible, so as of now I have the 2.7.3 uploaded and also I have the js file uploaded directly not zipped. Also putting it in here that I am the platformresourceloader to laod the leaflet libraries as well.

```
import {
  loadStyle,
  loadScript
} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import leaflet from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/leaflet'
import ChartsJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartsJS';
      getAddressCharts(e) {
        // console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, ChartsJS + '/Chart.js')
          ]).then(() => {
                //d something
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Cant load CHARTJS");
          });
      }
```

Below are the screenshots:
404 Not Found:
[image]
[image]

EDIT: After apply sfdcfox solution
I was able to get rid of the 404 not found error. but now I get 'Cannot read property 'getContext' of null'

```
 <template if:true={showCharts}>
          <lightning-card title="Sand Samples" icon-name="utility:chart" key={address.key}>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
              <canvas class="linechart" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
            </div>
          </lightning-card>
        </template>

  @track showCharts = false;

  getAddressCharts(e) {
    // console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
    Promise.allSettled([
        loadScript(this, ChartsJS)
      ]).then(() => {
        console.log("Charts Loaded");

    this.showCharts = true;
    const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.linechart').getContext('2d');
    this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
    this.chart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = '100%';
    this.chart.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '100%';
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a zip, don't add a path at the end:

```
loadScript(this, ChartsJS)
```

All the examples in the docs use a ZIP file, but if you don't have one, no file name is required.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I was able to get rid of the 404 error, but still I am not able to load the chart. I am loading the chart on a button click, Now it says 'Cannot read property 'getContext' of null'. Could you please advise

Comment: Could this be related to the chart library I have loaded?

Comment: @sumchans `const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.linechart').getContext('2d');` seems to be the culprit? Make sure you're getting the correct element. Also, is it marked as `lwc:dom="manual"`? You'll probably need that to avoid any locker service errors.

Comment: Yes, I knew that, but I have everything setup perfectly, not sure where this happens.

Comment: I found the issue, but I dont know how to tackle it. The problem comes from having everything on one single method. In the above code inside the getAddressCharts method, I have three things happening, 1. I am loading the charts library, 2. setting the canvas template to true and 3. accessing the canvas element. I moved the chart loading and setting the canvas element to true code to the constructor then all of a sudden it works. But i want to have this all happen on button click. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sumchans Hmm, it should work. Tell you what, I'll set up a demo in my dev org and see what I can uncover. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @sumchans Actually, since you only have a fragment, would it be possible to send me a minimum viable reproduction I can deploy to my org? That'd save me a bit of time.

Comment: sure I can do that, but wondering how could I do it. Is it on the Playground?

Comment: @sumchans You can't package static resources on the playground. Can you wrap it up in a package or just download the files, zip it up, and send it to me? My email's on my profile.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the continued support. I just sent those files to you.

Comment: Not sure you got it, because I got a postmaster saying email was rejected by the provider.

Comment: @sumchans Yeah, I didn't get it. I was wondering about that. Try brianfear at comcast.net. I don't monitor that email frequently, but I'll watch out for your message.

Comment: Just sent it out to you. Hope that helps. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox, I applied the tweak that you mentioned on another post that i put in yesterday I used setTimeout function to give it bit of a delay, that helped for the itme being.